# Define a section in SASS/SCSS that should stay untouched

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I would like to define a section of my SASS/SCSS file that is not touched when compiled into CSS. I need to define some php code at the top that I would like to stay untouched, like this:

```
<?php ... ?>

body {
...
}
```

Is this possible using SASS/SCSS/Compass?

Comment: one dirty way I can think of is to edit the compass compiler itself, but I do not recommend that

Answer (score 0):

"Stay untouched" as in do not compile to CSS?

Comment: As in a piece of code that I want to be preserved exactly like I wrote it when compiles to CSS. In other words, I want a block of code to be exactly the same in the .scss file, and .css file. Just copied from one file to another.

Comment: Can you give a more clear real world use case? Share a code block and show how you want it to remain the same please.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing PHP in your CSS? If `.css` is the extension it will not be interpreted as PHP.

Assuming it was, though, maybe try:

```
/* 
<?php echo '*/'; 

//PHP goes here

echo '/*'; ?>
*/
```

(Anything inside `/* */` will be untouched in the compiled CSS)